# Why is the compiler package discontinued in Python 3?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, python-3.x

I was just pleasantly surprised to came across the documentation of [Python's compiler package](http://docs.python.org/library/compiler), but noticed that it's gone in Python 3.0, without any clear replacement or explanation.

I can't seem to find any discussion on python-dev about how this decision was made - does anyone have any insight inot this decision?

Comment: Note that for many Python 3.x changes, you need to search the archives for the python-3000 list in addition to python-dev. For example, one discussion of this decision can be seen at: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-January/011693.html

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I believe the functionality is now built in:

- [compile](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile)
- [ast](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html)

Comment: To expand on this answer: the compiler package was an absolute pain to maintain and almost always either slightly out of date or subtly different from the "real" compiler. Making it easier to work with the real compiler via the `ast` module made maintenance a lot easier while still providing similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

To provide specific references to the decision trail:

- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007577.html
- [PEP 3108](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/)

And, for what it's worth, I started Python3 port of the compiler package, to be maintained outside of the stdlib:

- https://github.com/pfalcon/python-compiler
- https://pypi.org/project/python-compiler/

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I started a port of the `compiler` package to Python3: https://github.com/pfalcon/python-compiler . At the time of writing, it generates bytecode compatible with CPython3.5, and can compiler entire standard library of that version.