# "compiler" module py3k

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to port a codebase which uses the "compiler" module from 2.x over to 3.1 ; I get an ImportError at

```
import compiler
```

as the module does not exist in Python3.x ; Has the same functionality been integrated into another module within the standard library? 
Or has it been completely removed?

**[EDIT]**
I require an equivalent for `compiler.parse.getChildren` in Py3k.

Comment: Similar to, though not identical with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909092/why-is-the-compiler-package-discontinued-in-python-3

Answer (score 7):

[According to the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/compiler.html?highlight=compiler#module-compiler), the module has been deprecated since 2.6 and been completely removed in 3.0.

From [PEP 3108](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/):

- Having to maintain both the built-in compiler and the stdlib package is redundant [(24)](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007615.html).
- The AST created by the compiler is available [(23)](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html).
- Mechanism to compile from an AST needs to be added.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you want to do. The abstract syntax tree stuff has largely been moved into the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module.

Apparently the [compile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile) built in function can compile an AST object to bytecode which (coarsely) handles the remaining functionality of the `compiler` module. I've also never done this so YMMV.