# determining numerator and denominator in a relatively complex mathematical expression using python

Tags: python, math, algebra

I'm trying to convert calculator input to LaTeX. if a user inputs this:

```
(3x^(x+(5/x)+(x/33))+y)/(32 + 5)
```

I have to convert it to this:

```
frac{3x^(x+frac{5}{x}+frac{x}{33})+y}{32 + 5x}
```

however I am having issues with determining when a numerator begins and ends. Any suggestions?

Comment: You've missed `x` in `(32 + 5)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A package already exists for this kind of transformation : [Py2Tex](http://www.sollunae.net/py2tex/)

If you want to reuse this package, you can use the `py2tex.Interpret` class to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [compiler](http://docs.python.org/library/compiler.html?highlight=compiler#module-compiler)

```
compiler.parse('(3*x**(x+(5/x)+(x/33))+y)/(32 + 5)')
```

returns

```
Module(None, Stmt([Discard(Div((Add((Mul((Const(3), Power((Name('x'), Add((Add((Name('x'), Div((Const(5), Name('x'))))), Div((Name('x'), Const(33))))))))), Name('y'))), Add((Const(32), Const(5))))))]))
```

which could be more easily converted to LaTeX code. You will have to write methods, that handle each code (Div, Add, Const, Name, Power,...) and its parameters recursively and return appropriate LateX code.

Comment: The `^` needs to be replaced with `**` otherwise Python will treat it as the `Bitwise-XOR` operator.

Comment: i am testing that out, though i do not understand the return value at the moment, thanks.

Comment: @sukhbir - I have already replaced `3x` with `3*x`, and now edited your remark, thank you.

Comment: @eumiro: :-) This seems like a nice solution, though I will wait for the OP to confirm whether this works (I am thinking how will this be converted to LaTex) before giving you an upvote!

Comment: @sukhbir: this could very well work, but i am unsure with what to do with the return value. i'm playing with that at the moment.

Comment: @tipu - see the given link for compiler - it has a list of all types of objects and their respective parameters.

Comment: this is pretty much the answer that will gets me closer to my goal. next problem is figuring out the nodes and their children =)

Comment: Do not use the 'compiler' module, it is deprecated since 2.6. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909092/why-is-the-compiler-package-discontinued-in-python-3

Comment: It's impossible to preserve brackets and ordering with this method, otherwise a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to use the exact syntax from your question then you could write [a parser for the calculator](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/api/lepl-module.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from operator import add, div, mul, sub

from lepl  import Any, Delayed, Digit, Drop, DroppedSpace, Eos
from sympy import Symbol, latex, pprint

def Power(tokens):
    """x**(y**z)"""
    return reduce(lambda p, b: pow(b, p), reversed(tokens))

def Arithm(tokens):
    """(x op1 y) op2 z ..."""
    OP = { '*': mul, '/': div, '+': add, '-': sub, }
    tokens = iter(tokens)
    a = next(tokens)
    for op, b in zip(tokens, tokens):
        a = OP[op](a, b)
    return a

def makeparser():
    expr = Delayed()
    number = Digit()[1:,...] >> int # \d+
    symbol = Any('xyz') >> (lambda x: Symbol(bytes(x))) # unicode -> str
    muldiv_op = Any('*/')[:1] > (lambda x: x[0] if x else '*') # xy -> x*y
    power_op = Drop('^') | Drop('**') # both stand for pow(x, y)

    with DroppedSpace(): # ignore spaces
        term = number | symbol | Drop('(') & expr & Drop(')')
        power   = term & (power_op  & term)[:] > Power
        factor = power & (muldiv_op & power)[:] > Arithm
        expr += factor & (Any('-+') & factor)[:] > Arithm
        line = expr & Eos()
    return line.get_parse()

parse = makeparser()
[expr] = parse('(3x^(x+(5/x)+(x/33))+y)/(32 + 5)')
pprint(expr)
print(latex(expr))
```

#### Output

```
        34⋅x   5
        ──── + ─
         33    x
y    3⋅x        
── + ───────────
37        37    
$\frac{1}{37} y + \frac{3}{37} x^{\frac{34}{33} x + \frac{5}{x}}$
```

In general it might be preferable to use syntax for an existing language such as Python.