# Is there a 3rd party compiler for python?

Tags: python, compiler-construction

I want to compile python prototypes without having to re-code them in other languages so that i can use them in user machines (without python installed).
Does any one know a 3rd party compiler i can use? (python 3)

Comment: have a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909092/why-is-the-compiler-package-discontinued-in-python-3

Answer (score 3):

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) will allow you to create a standalone executable from a python application, which you can then redistribute (to machines that do not have python).  However, it is not a compiler.

Comment: The only problem is, that according to their webpage it is not python 3 ready yet, so maybe cx_freeze might work better: http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to what you're asking for is [Cython](http://cython.org/).

Answer (score 1):

"Cython - is a language that makes writing C extensions for the Python language as easy as Python itself. Cython is based on the well-known Pyrex, but supports more cutting edge functionality and optimizations - http://cython.org/"

"py2exe - is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a Python installation - http://www.py2exe.org/"

```
You can use them without needing to install Python on your computer.
```