# Pyan module throwing error with Python 3.4 version

Tags: python, call-graph

I am doing a static analysis of Python code. The Python version my system has is 3.4.3. When I run the Pyan module to draw call graph, it throws an error in the Pyan code.

Answer (score 0):

pyan relies on the compiler package which has been deprecated since 2.6 and removed in Python3.

There's currently an [open ticket](https://github.com/johnyf/pyan/issues/3) on the GitHub project to rewrite pyan for Python 3.

If you were so inclined you could look into [updating pyan to use Python3 yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909092/why-is-the-compiler-package-discontinued-in-python-3).