# Python: make eval safe

Tags: python, eval

I want an easy way to do a "calculator API" in Python.

Right now I don't care much about the exact set of features the calculator is going to support.

I want it to receive a string, say `"1+1"` and return a string with the result, in our case `"2"`.

Is there a way to make `eval` safe for such a thing?

For a start I would do

```
env = {}
env["locals"]   = None
env["globals"]  = None
env["__name__"] = None
env["__file__"] = None
env["__builtins__"] = None

eval(users_str, env)
```

so that the caller cannot mess with my local variables (or see them).

But I am sure I am overseeing a lot here.

Are `eval`'s security issues fixable or are there just too many tiny details to get it working right?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python

Comment: Is this can solve your issue https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d7cfa8c502f27bee5c2fccb35db47b08e3b3804b/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py

Answer (score 78, accepted):

> are eval's security issues fixable or
>   are there just too many tiny details
>   to get it working right?

Definitely the latter -- a clever hacker will always manage to find a way around your precautions.

If you're satisfied with plain expressions using elementary-type literals only, use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html?highlight=literal#ast.literal_eval) -- that's what it's for!  For anything fancier, I recommend a parsing package, such as [ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) if you're familiar and comfortable with the classic lexx/yacc approach, or [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) for a possibly more Pythonic approach.

Comment: It is still possible to crash `ast.literal_eval` :/

Comment: It doesn't work for extended math, example `3*2`.

Comment: New pyparsing link: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/

Comment: ast.literal_eval was exactly what I needed. Thanks Alex!

Answer (score 15):

It is possible to get access to *any* class that has been defined in the process, and then you can instantiate it and invoke methods on it.  It is possible to segfault the CPython interpreter, or make it quit. See this:  [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Answer (score 1):

The security issues are not (even close to) fixable.

I would use [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) to parse the expression into a list of tokens (this should not be too difficult, because the grammar is straightforward) and then handle the tokens individually.

You could also use the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.parse) module to build a Python AST (since you are using valid Python syntax), but this may be open to subtle security holes.

Comment: I think this doesn't work, because I set locals and globals to None so they are not visible from inside the eval expression.

Comment: @flybywire: apologies, that is true; edited. Still a bad idea though.

Comment: @flybywire: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings

Comment: @katrielalex can you please list the issues you see with the eval's security. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings on SO and @jerub provides a link to the problems with eval. Apart from that, are there any other issues that one needs to be aware of?

Comment: @Ganga, have you thought for example about how `(1).__class__.__bases__[0].__subclasses__()` gives you **every** class existing in your system?  Just for starters...

Comment: @Gangadhar: Off the top of my head, you can raise an error from e.g. `users_str = "[[]]*8**50"`. I'll see if I can find another way around -- but even if I can't, there's no guarantee *nobody* can.

Comment: it is possible to crash python interpreter with `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 1):

Perl has a Safe eval module http://perldoc.perl.org/Safe.html

Googling "Python equivalent of Perl Safe" finds
http://docs.python.org/2/library/rexec.html

but this Python "restricted exec" is deprecated.

--

overall, "eval" security, in any language, is a big issue.  SQL injection attacks are just an example of such a security hole.  Perl Safe has had security bugs over the years - most recent one I remember, it was safe, except for destructors on objects returned from the safe eval.

It's the sort of thing that i might use for my own tools, but not web exposed.

However, I hope that someday fully secure evals will be available in many / any languages.