# Is there a way to secure strings for Python's eval?

Tags: python, security, eval

There are many questions on SO about using Python's eval on **insecure strings** (eg.: [Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings), [Python: make eval safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513292/python-make-eval-safe)). The unanimous answer is that this is a bad idea.

However, I found little information on which strings can be considered safe (if any).
Now I'm wondering if there is a definition of "safe strings" available (eg.: a string that only contains lower case ascii chars or any of the signs +-*/()). The exploits I found generally relied on either of _.,:[]'" or the like. Can such an approach be secure (for use in a graph painting web application)?

Otherwise, I guess using a parsing package as Alex Martelli suggested is the only way.

EDIT:
Unfortunately, there are neither answers that give a compelling explanation for why/ how the above strings are to be considered insecure (a tiny working exploit) nor explanations for the contrary. I am aware that using eval should be avoided, but that's not the question. Hence, I'll award a bounty to the first who comes up with either a working exploit or a really good explanation why a string mangled as described above is to be considered (in)secure.

Comment: You can do pretty much whatever you want with ASCII characters and `eval`. Filtering for only those won't do much.

Comment: I wonder if using eval is a good idea? Perhaps it's better to have a user interface which behind the scenes performs some operations or even have a simple "language" which you can parse and process? There are nice parsing libraries - http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/ and http://www.acooke.org/lepl/ available for Python?

Comment: @Waleed Khan: could you please point to any example?

Comment: I think it's worth taking a look at Ned Batchelder's [blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: Mark Pilgrim also gives a small hint on what can be done with eval (http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/advanced-iterators.html#eval) and concludes... """Say it with me: "eval() is evil!"""" ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here you have a working "exploit" with your restrictions in place - only contains lower case ascii chars or any of the signs +-*/()  .
It relies on a 2nd eval layer.

```
def mask_code( python_code ):
    s="+".join(["chr("+str(ord(i))+")" for i in python_code])
    return "eval("+s+")"

bad_code='''__import__("os").getcwd()'''
masked= mask_code( bad_code )
print masked
print eval(bad_code)
```

output:

```
eval(chr(111)+chr(115)+chr(46)+chr(103)+chr(101)+chr(116)+chr(99)+chr(119)+chr(100)+chr(40)+chr(41))
/home/user
```

This is a **very trivial** "exploit". I'm sure there's countless others, even with further character restrictions.
It bears repeating that one should always use a parser or ast.literal_eval(). Only by parsing the tokens can one be sure the string is safe to evaluate. Anything else is betting against the house.

Comment: Thanks - this is an excellent and very illustrative example for the trouble one could run into with eval!

Comment: See also below about RestrictedPython. Making your AST tree evaluation safe is not trivial either, but possible.

Comment: One could restrict builtins access to forbid a recursive eval layer, but this is only a drop in the ocean...

Answer (score 9):

No, there isn't, or at least, not a sensible, truly secure way. Python is a highly dynamic language, and the flipside of that is that it's very easy to subvert any attempt to lock the language down.

You either need to write your own parser for the subset you want, or use something existing, like `ast.literal_eval()`, for particular cases as you come across them. Use a tool designed for the job at hand, rather than trying to force an existing one to do the job you want, badly.

Edit:

An example of two strings, that, while fitting your description, if `eval()`ed in order, would execute arbitrary code (this particular example running `evil.__method__()`.

```
"from binascii import *"
"eval(unhexlify('6576696c2e5f5f6d6574686f645f5f2829'))"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about ast.literal_eval as it's in the answer of the quoted questions. Could you maybe provide any example for an exploit of the scenario provided in the question? In that case I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @GeraldSenarclensdeGrancy See my edit, it's pretty trivial to work around such a limitation. I'm sure someone more versed in security could find far, far more significant problems. Sandboxing Python has been tried many a time, and it's not an easy task.

Comment: +1 on this.  As a side note, if you really seriously need to run user python code, it's at least theoretically possible to do it safely with a PyPy sandbox (CPython is much harder to sandbox).

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, it does not fit my description for two reasons: "from binascii import *" is not allowed by eval per se. It leads to "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Circumventing this via __import__ wouldn't work as _ is not in the whitelist. The second string wouldn't work either ad ' is not in the whitelist either. It would lead to eval(unhexlify(6576696c2e5f5f6d6574686f645f5f2829)) and even with unhexify available would lead to "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Comment: @GeraldSenarclensdeGrancy While my example may not work, I'm not an expert on this kind of thing - if I can get that close, with some time and effort, I'm sure it'd be easy enough to do. What you are trying to do is a bad idea, because you are using a tool for a task it wasn't designed for - it's too easy for something to go wrong.

Comment: @Lattyware: I do believe you (in that eval is generally evil for that kind of task) and am thankful for your insights. I had used this (bad) idea some time ago and disabled it before posting here in the first place. However, the approach had its charms in terms of simplicity. Meanwhile I still am curious about real exploits... so I guess I'll edit the question add a bounty once eligible.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Remembering that there are no guarantees (although RestrictedPython is a really cool project). If you need to sandbox python, great, but in most cases, ``eval()`` is a shortcut hack which is better replaced with other code, safe or not.

Comment: @Lattyware In the context of untrusted code execution, which for me translates code submitted by a client, RestrictedPython is your only and best hope.

Comment: Indeed, as I said, if you *need* to run untrusted code - that's what it's for, but often these things get used for the wrong reasons, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

An exploit similar to goncalopp's but that also satisfy the restriction that the string `'eval'` is not a substring of the exploit:

```
def to_chrs(text):
    return '+'.join('chr(%d)' % ord(c) for c in text)

def _make_getattr_call(obj, attr):
    return 'getattr(*(list(%s for a in chr(1)) + list(%s for a in chr(1))))' % (obj, attr)

def make_exploit(code):
    get = to_chrs('get')
    builtins = to_chrs('__builtins__')
    eval = to_chrs('eval')
    code = to_chrs(code)
    return (_make_getattr_call(
                _make_getattr_call('globals()', '{get}') + '({builtins})',
                '{eval}') + '({code})').format(**locals())
```

It uses a combination of genexp and tuple unpacking to call `getattr` with two arguments without using the comma.

An example usage:

```
>>> exploit =  make_exploit('__import__("os").system("echo $PWD")')
>>> print exploit
getattr(*(list(getattr(*(list(globals() for a in chr(1)) + list(chr(103)+chr(101)+chr(116) for a in chr(1))))(chr(95)+chr(95)+chr(98)+chr(117)+chr(105)+chr(108)+chr(116)+chr(105)+chr(110)+chr(115)+chr(95)+chr(95)) for a in chr(1)) + list(chr(101)+chr(118)+chr(97)+chr(108) for a in chr(1))))(chr(95)+chr(95)+chr(105)+chr(109)+chr(112)+chr(111)+chr(114)+chr(116)+chr(95)+chr(95)+chr(40)+chr(34)+chr(111)+chr(115)+chr(34)+chr(41)+chr(46)+chr(115)+chr(121)+chr(115)+chr(116)+chr(101)+chr(109)+chr(40)+chr(34)+chr(101)+chr(99)+chr(104)+chr(111)+chr(32)+chr(36)+chr(80)+chr(87)+chr(68)+chr(34)+chr(41))
>>> eval(exploit)
/home/giacomo
0
```

This proves that to define restrictions only on the text that make the code safe is really hard. Even things like `'eval' in code` are not safe. Either you must remove the possibility of executing a function call at all, or you must remove **all** dangerous built-ins from `eval`'s environment. My exploit also shows that `getattr` is as bad as `eval` even when you can not use the comma, since it allows you to walk arbitrary into the object hierarchy. For example you can obtain the real `eval` function even if the environment does not provide it:

```
def real_eval():
    get_subclasses = _make_getattr_call(
                         _make_getattr_call(
                             _make_getattr_call('()',
                                 to_chrs('__class__')),
                             to_chrs('__base__')),
                         to_chrs('__subclasses__')) + '()'

    catch_warnings = 'next(c for c in %s if %s == %s)()' % (get_subclasses,
                                                            _make_getattr_call('c',
                                                                to_chrs('__name__')),
                                                            to_chrs('catch_warnings'))

    return _make_getattr_call(
               _make_getattr_call(
                   _make_getattr_call(catch_warnings, to_chrs('_module')),
                   to_chrs('__builtins__')),
               to_chrs('get')) + '(%s)' % to_chrs('eval')


>>> no_eval = __builtins__.__dict__.copy()
>>> del no_eval['eval']
>>> eval(real_eval(), {'__builtins__': no_eval})
<built-in function eval>
```

Even though if you remove all the built-ins, then the code becomes safe:

```
>>> eval(real_eval(), {'__builtins__': None})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'getattr' is not defined
```

Note that setting `'__builtins__'` to `None` removes also `chr`, `list`, `tuple` etc.
The combo of your character restrinctions *and* `'__builtins__'` to `None` is completely safe, because the user has no way to access anything. He can't use the `.`, the brackets `[]` or any built-in function or type.

Even though I must say in this way what you can evaluate is pretty limited. You can't do much more than do operations on numbers.

Probably it's enough to remove `eval`, `getattr`, and `chr` from the built-ins to make the code safe, at least I can't think of a way to write an exploit that does not use one of them.

A "parsing" approach is probably safer and gives more flexibility. For example [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496746-restricted-safe-eval/) recipe is pretty good and is also easily customizable to add more restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for this very informative answer! As you say - it is essentially the same as goncalopp's, even without relying on eval. It would be nice if you could demonstrate an application of this exploit as goncalopp did, eg s = make_exploit("__import__('os').getcwd()"); eval(s)

Comment: @GeraldSenarclensdeGrancy I've added an exaple of its usage.

Comment: As I really liked the simplicity of goncalopp's answer, I accepted it so others who just want a quick peek on what is possible will see it faster; however, you received the bounty; thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

To study how to make safe eval I suggest RestrictedPython module (over 10 years of production usage, one fine piece of Python software)

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython

RestrictedPython takes Python source code and modifies its AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) to make the evaluation safe within the sandbox, without leaking any Python internals which might allow to escape the sandbox.

From RestrictedPython source code you'll learn what kind of tricks are needed to perform to make Python sandboxed safe.

Comment: Please note that this answer is outdated and there doesn't exist RestrictedPython for Python 3.4 yet.

Comment: A lot of things happen in 7 years :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably should avoid eval, actually.

But if your stuck with it, you could just make sure your strings are alphanumeric. That should be safe.

Comment: Well, you can't do much with only alphanumeric strings. You can represent only numbers and identifiers... at that point you can do much more things with `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the named functions exist and are safe:

```
if re.match("^(?:safe|soft|cotton|ball|[()])+$", code): eval(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to create input sanitization routines. You must also ensure that sanitization is not once accidentally omitted. One way to do that is [taint checking](http://www.pythonsecurity.org/wiki/taintmode/).