# Convert string representation of multiIndex pandas into multiIndex pandas in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have a string representation of a multiIndex below.

```
iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']]
df = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])
df = str(df)
```

I would like to convert string represented **df** back into a **pandas multiIndex class**. Are there any direct functions available in pandas for the same?

Excepted output:

```
print(df)
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
       names=['first', 'second'])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your expected out put ?

Comment: MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['first', 'second'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string representation of the MultiIndex is nearly executable code, so you could evaluate it with `eval`, like this:

```
eval(df, {}, {'MultiIndex': pd.MultiIndex})
# MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
#        labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
#        names=[u'first', u'second'])
```

Just be careful that you have control of the string you pass to `eval`, since it could be used to crash your computer and/or run arbitrary code (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513292/python-make-eval-safe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804961/python-eval-is-it-still-dangerous-if-i-disable-builtins-and-attribute-access)).

Alternatively, here's a safe and simple but somewhat brittle way to do this:

```
import ast
# convert df into a literal string defining a dictionary
dfd = (
    "{" + df[11:-1] + "}"
        .replace("levels=", "'levels':")
        .replace("labels=", "'labels':")
        .replace("names=", "'names':") 
)
# convert it safely into an actual dictionary
args = ast.literal_eval(dfd)
# use the dictionary as arguments to pd.MultiIndex
pd.MultiIndex(**args)
```

With this code, there's no way for arbitrary strings to crash your computer, since `ast.literal_eval()` doesn't allow any operators, just literal expressions.

Here's a version that's safe and doesn't require pre-specifying the argument names, but it's more complex:

```
import ast, tokenize
from cStringIO import StringIO
tokens = [  # make a list of mutable tokens
    list(t) 
    for t in tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO('{' + df[11:-1] + '}').readline)
]
for t, next_t in zip(tokens[:-1], tokens[1:]):
    # convert `identifier=` to `'identifier':`
    if t[0] == 1 and next_t[0] == 51 and next_t[1] == '=':
        t[0] = 3                  # switch type to quoted string
        t[1] = "'" + t[1] + "'"   # put quotes around identifier
        next_t[1] = ':'           # convert '=' to ':' 
args = ast.literal_eval(tokenize.untokenize(tokens))
pd.MultiIndex(**args)
```

Note that this code will raise an exception if `df` is malformed or contains  'identifier=...' as code (not inside strings) at lower levels. But I don't think that can happen with `str(MultiIndex)`. If that is an issue, you could generate an `ast` tree for the original `df` string, then extract the arguments and convert those programmatically into a literal definition for a `dict` (`{x: y}`, not `dict(x=y)`), then use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate that.