# How to store and use mathematical operators as python variable

Tags: python

I am new to python and was trying to write something like this below (code A) so it does eactly like code B. I want to make use of user input of mathematical operators as `do_what` variable. How can we write this code (A) in python so it would work like code B?

code A

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
do_what = input("Enter a calculation symbol for calculation you want to perform: ")
result = float(num1) do_what float(num2)
print("result is: " + str(result))
```

code B

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
result = int(num1) + int(num2)
print("result is: " + str(result))
```

Comment: Does it have to appear like an infix operator?

Comment: Not sure what infix means, but it could be variable- +, -, X etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [operator module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html) for common operators and make a lookup dictionary to map symbols to functions. If you want operators not in that module, you can simply define custom functions and add look them up the same way:

```
import operator

operatorlookup = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv
}

num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
do_what = input("Enter calculation symbols for calculation you want to perform: ")

op = operatorlookup.get(do_what)

if op is not None:
    result = op(float(num1), float(num2))
else:
    result = "Unknown operator"
print("result is: " + str(result))
```

Answer (score 6):

You might also be interested in knowing about the inbuilt function [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). This reduces the `if` and `else` loops to a single statement for this particular example of yours

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
do_what = input("Enter calculation symbols for calculation you want to perform: ")

result = eval(num1 + do_what + num2)
print("result is: %s" %result)

# Enter a number: 3
# Enter another number: 18
# Enter calculation symbols for calculation you want to perform: *
# result is: 54
```

**EDIT**

To make `eval` slightly safe in this particular case, you can perhaps use something like this

```
if do_what in ['+', '-', '*', '**', '/']:
    result = eval(num1 + do_what + num2)
    print("result is: %s" %result)
else:
    print ("Enter an arithmetic operator")
```

Comment: I have seen a bunch of times where `eval` is not recommended but it seems to be getting the job done. Are there downsides that one needs to worry about?

Comment: @hqkhan: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9384005/4932316) answer. As per one comment, it seems that as long as your `input` is not directly within `eval()`, you are fine

Comment: @hqkhan: Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804961/python-eval-is-it-still-dangerous-if-i-disable-builtins-and-attribute-access) is worth reading

Comment: @hqkhan: Check my edit. That makes it slightly safer

Answer (score 2):

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
do_what = input("Enter calculation symbols for calculation you want to perform: ")
if do_what=='+':
    result = float(num1) + float(num2)
elif do_what=='-':
    result = float(num1) - float(num2)
elif do_what=='*':
    result = float(num1) * float(num2)
elif do_what=='/':
    result = float(num1) / float(num2)
print("result is: " + str(result))
```

Comment: Thanks! this works, but would be nice to just replace the symbol with `do_what`

Answer (score 0):

If security is not your concern you could use eval to achieve this

```
result = eval(str(num1) + do_what + str(num2))
```

The problem is that eval literally evaluates everything you write as python code, so don't do this if you mean for this to be used by others