# Is this usage of eval() safe?

Tags: python, eval, malware

Here is the situation: I am building application that can take a mathematical expression and evaluate it (works as a calculator). I do not have the `os` module imported, so I probably would not be able to execute `rm -rf /` or anything super malicious like that; but I want to be completely sure. I stumbled across the parser module in Python, and it has a parser function that claims to be much safer than eval. There is somewhere eval() shows up:

```
    expression = expression.split(";")

    expression_outputs = []

    for i in range(len(expression)):
        result = parser.expr(expression[i].strip()).compile()
        expression_outputs.append(complex(eval(result)))
    
    print("Answer(s): " + str(expression_outputs))
```

Is this code safe? If not, what would be some alternatives?

Comment: if `ast.literal_eval` would work for you, it would be more safe. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: The os module is part of the standard library, so it is installed already.

Comment: It depends whether the user can type anything into `expression`. For example, I made a calculator that limits what the user can type, so in my case `eval` is relatively safe.

Comment: You aren't providing the important detail, where does `expression` come from? If it is from untrusted input, then yes, this is an unsafe use of `eval`. I'm not sure what you mean "I do not have the os module installed", that is part of the standard library.

Comment: ```expression``` is what the user puts in. Also, I meant to say "imported" when I said "installed" (my bad). ```expression``` is heavily modified before being parsed (the main thing being done is the addition of math and cmath, so a user can type sin(0) instead of having to type cmath.sin(0)).

Comment: Sanitizing input will make it safer, but it is never safe as eval will execute the input given to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python eval: is it still dangerous if I disable builtins and attribute access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804961/python-eval-is-it-still-dangerous-if-i-disable-builtins-and-attribute-access)

Comment: @PythonProgrammer314 please provide a *complete example*. Anyway, the fact that you aren't importing `os` is irrelevant. The code you are evaluating could import `os`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ```expression``` is defined here if this answers your question: ```expression = input("Write an expression or set of expressions seperated by semicolons: ")```