# How to convert a string representation of a list without double quoted elements to an actual list?

Tags: python, string

I have referred to many sources but most use `json.loads()` or `ast.literal_eval()` which doesn't work for my case:

```
x = '[(0.0, 58.099669), 56565, Raining]'
```

Intended output:

```
x = [(0.0, 58.099669), 56565, 'Raining']
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Should the `None` become the *string* `'None'`, or an actual `None` object? How will you be able to tell?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for pointing this out. I have since edited and removed the None as I don't think that should be the point of this question. The main objective here is to convert the string of a list without double quoted elements into a string. I believe I could deal with None from there on.

Comment: What created this text? We can offer de-facto solutions, but it might not fit the real problem.

Comment: There is a broader point to this, though. The entire reason you're only finding tools that deal with data with quotes in it, is that *you need the quotes to avoid ambiguity*.

Comment: You can always write a parser, but you can't write it until you know the variability of your input data.

Comment: I see, thank you for the comments. I see the point of the double quotes now. This text is generated from a database representation of the underlying data. I doubt I have access to change the data structure from within. For this particular instance, the format is fixed: [(A, B), C, D ,E]' where A, B, C, D and E could only be alphanumeric. Yes, I have thought of a regex parser but I was thinking if there exists a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
class default_key(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return key

d = default_key()
x = '[(0.0, 58.099669), 56565, Raining]'

res = eval(x, d, {})
# res = [(0.0, 58.099669), 56565, 'Raining']
```

Explanation: `eval` normally uses the `globals()` and `locals()` dict. However if you don't provide `locals()` and replace `globals()` with a dict that returns the name of a key when a lookup is done (and the key isn't found), then every 'variable' name in the given list will be converted to a string when `eval` is called.

This could still be unsafe however. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804961/python-eval-is-it-still-dangerous-if-i-disable-builtins-and-attribute-access).

Comment: This has worked very beautifully for me! Thank you so much for this clever solution!