# Removing the apostrophe from the list items

Tags: python, arrays, list, apostrophe

I have the following list in Python:

```
['[0,0]', '[0,1]', '[1,0]', '[1,1]']
```

How can I remove the apostrophes around each list item?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did that list come from?  The fix might be as simple as removing an errant `str()` call somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval` [carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804961/python-eval-is-it-still-dangerous-if-i-disable-builtins-and-attribute-access):

```
>>> [eval(l) for l in lst]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Or `json.loads`:

```
import json

>>> [json.loads(l) for l in lst]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` would work in favor of `eval` (which is extremely insecure)

Comment: @Wondercricket - Use eval "carefully" ;). See the attached link.