# Is it safe to use Python's eval() in a unit-test for __repr__?

Tags: python, unit-testing, eval

`eval()` has been called [evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/311507),  [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35804961), [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940), and so on an so forth.

Although I tend to avoid using `eval()`, I'm now tempted to use it in a unit-test for a custom implementation of `__repr__` (as discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr/2626364#comment40619938_1436756)).

Based on the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) for `__repr__`:

> ... If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that *could* be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). ...

(although [opinions differ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436756) as to whether this is very useful)

I would be tempted to test `MyClass.__repr__` as follows:

```py
assert eval(repr(my_class_instance)) == my_class_instance
```

(assuming `MyClass.__eq__` tests equality, not identity, [see comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127162/is-it-safe-to-use-pythons-eval-in-a-unit-test-for-repr?noredirect=1#comment126707793_71127162))

Which brings me to my question:

*Assuming we use "online" test runners, for CI/CD, would this usage of `eval()` introduce any security risks?*

I don't think it would, seeing that the input to `eval()` is *known* and *trusted*, but I'm no security expert...

Comment: @Maggyero You are [right](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__), thanks for pointing that out. My implementation of `MyClass` did override `__eq__`, so the outer `repr()` calls were not necessary there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` is said to be evil because when you eval a string that has been provided by a user, you implicitely allow them to execute arbitrary code.

By here you are using a hard coded string. To be able to execute arbitrary code, an attacker would have to modify the test code or the `__repr__` one. In either case that means that they would already have the possibility to execute arbitrary code, regardless of your use of `eval`.

So my opinion is that there is not security problem with using `eval` here. At most, you could add a comment for future readers explaining that you have examined that usage and decided that it added no security risk.