# Accessing instance variables using "self" via ast.Parse, compile, and exec

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, self

Don't ask me why... I have a need to allow users to write expressions that get stored on an object. These expressions need access to the objects instance attributes on which they're stored. My current plan is to

1. store the expression string
2. parse with ast
3. use a ast.NodeTransformer to replace the relevant NAME() nodes with nodes that
   access the instance attributes ("val1 > val2" to self.val1 >
   self.val2)
4. compile and store on the ojbect
5. exec the compiled ast when needed

Is there a way to access the objects self reference from the ast? I've tried the below and I'm not getting the output I would expect. The attribute node looks right to me, so I'm assuming something is going wrong with the objects self reference.

Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
class test_obj:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.value = 0

    def get_value(self):
        tree = ast.parse(ast.parse("self.value", "exec"))
        exe = compile(ast.parse("self.value", "exec"), "", "exec")
        print(f"Noraml access: {self.value}")
        print(f"Tree dump: {ast.dump(tree)}")
        print(f"Exec: {exec(exe)}")


a = test_obj()
a.get_value()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Noraml access: 0

Tree dump: Module(body=[Expr(value=Attribute(value=Name(id='self', ctx=Load()), 
attr='value', ctx=Load()))], type_ignores=[])

Exec: None
```

Comment: `exec` returns `None`, no matter what it executes. Are you looking for `eval`?

Comment: If you're going to be using `exec`/`eval`, there's no need to transform anything: just execute the code with the object's `__dict__` attribute as the global environment.

Comment: @jasonharper: That will create a `__builtins__` entry in the object's `__dict__`, which is typically undesirable.

Comment: @user2357112 yes i think you're right I've tried both ways but no success.

Comment: @jasonharper this worked but it did create a  `__builtins__`  entry in the objects dict. Do you see any issue with making a copy of the objects dict for each call of the method and using that as the `__global`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you intend with the nested call to `ast.parse` in:

```py
tree = ast.parse(ast.parse("self.value", "exec"))
```

The outer call is a no-op, as it happens, and the `"exec"` in the inner call is the filename, not the mode (although the mode will also be `exec` --i.e. a sequence of statements-- because that's the default value). (It's usually a good idea to name named arguments, and especially named arguments which follow arguments with default values.)

The AST returned by `ast.parse(..., mode="exec")` is a `Module` AST object, which is the AST type used to hold a sequence of statements at the outer level. You can call either `exec` or `eval` on a compiled `Module` AST; I don't believe there is a semantic difference. Either way, no value is returned. (Similarly, you can call `exec` on a compiled `Expression`; the return value is discarded. But this case isn't documented afaik.)

If you want to store a compiled `Expression` AST and be able to retrieve the result of evaluating the expression, you'll need to specify `mode="eval"` both when creating the AST and when calling `compile`. So you might end up with a test harness which looks like the below. (This is OK for testing but for production use, please read the note on insecurity at the end of this answer).

This code requires Python 3.9 for the `indent` argument to `ast.dump`, which makes the output more readable (at least, for me). But it's not essential.

```py
import ast

class test_obj:
    def __init__(self, value=42):
        self.value = value

    def get_value(self, expr="self.value"):
        tree = ast.parse(expr, filename="<get_value>", mode="eval")
        exe = compile(tree, filename="<get_value>", mode="eval")
        print(f"self.value = {self.value}")
        print(f"Tree dump: {ast.dump(tree, indent=2)}")
        print(f"Exec: {eval(exe)}")

a = test_obj(17)
a.get_value("self.value * 3")
```

This has what I suppose is the expected result:

```
self.value = 17
Tree dump: Expression(
  body=BinOp(
    left=Attribute(
      value=Name(id='self', ctx=Load()),
      attr='value',
      ctx=Load()),
    op=Mult(),
    right=Constant(value=3)))
Exec: 51
```

### Insecurity warning

I don't think the above is really safe, given that the expressions to evaluate are user input (and therefore untrusted). It would be better to restrict access to both global and local variables. As written, `eval` is called with defaults for both `globals` and `locals`, which means that the same identifiers are visible in the evaluated code as are visible in the method `get_value`:

```py
>>> a.get_value("__import__('os').system('echo ---------;echo Could have been rm -fR; echo ---------')")
self.value = 42
Tree dump: Expression(
  body=Call(
    func=Attribute(
      value=Call(
        func=Name(id='__import__', ctx=Load()),
        args=[
          Constant(value='os')],
        keywords=[]),
      attr='system',
      ctx=Load()),
    args=[
      Constant(value='echo ---------;echo Could have been rm -fR; echo ---------')],
    keywords=[]))
---------
Could have been rm -fR
---------
Exec: 0
```

I'd suggest replacing `eval(exe)` with `eval(exe, globals={'self':self})`; if that doesn't provide all the global identifiers you think your users might need, you (cautiously) add others to the supplied global dictionary.

Comment: You're right that was a typo. I have solved the problem by creating a copy of the objects `__dict__`and then passing it to a `safe_parse(exp, globals)` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48135793/17154259) function which raises exceptions if unsafe nodes are parsed.  This limits the operations available and provides access the objects attributes without needing to replace nodes in the tree