# Pandas load_table string to tuple conversion

Tags: python, tuples, pandas

I use a lot of tuples in my data files as record keys. When I load a table from text the tuples are strings in the dataframe.

I convert to tuple now, using:

```
df['KEY'] = df['KEY'].map(lambda x: eval(x))
```

Is it possible to get the string evaluation automatically?

Luc

Comment: A slightly safer/better way is to use [`literal_eval`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3513475/1240268). I don't think you will be able to do this automatically...

Comment: Are these all of the same length? Does it make sense to include each item in the tuple as a separate column?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `converters={'KEY': eval}` to make things a bit simpler. It would be possible to add some more optimized version of this internally, too.

Comment: The suggestion of Wes does the trick, thanks, I will need this in almost all my pandas work...

Comment: How do we use converters={'KEY': eval} in the code you have mentioned in the question.