# Is it possible to restrict the builtins in PyPy?

Tags: pypy

According to the [PyPy docs](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html), "the **builtins** name is always referencing the **builtin** module, never a dictionary as it sometimes is in CPython. Assigning to **builtins** has no effect." For example in CPython:

```
>>> eval("__import__('os').system('clear')", {'__builtins__':{}})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__import__' is not defined
```

In PyPy it runs it without an error. Is there another way of restricting the builtins available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it was decided long ago that we don't offer this.  Maybe we can rethink it nowadays, but please note that it only gives a false sense of security.  Calling eval() on a string provided by a 3rd party is *never* safe, even if you use the trick of `{'__builtins__':{}}`.  See [Python: make eval safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513292/python-make-eval-safe).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that the empty `__builtins__` trick is not enough to ensure security on its own, this was just an example.