# How to convert tuple in string to tuple object?

Tags: python, tuples

In Python 2.7, I have the following string:

```
"((1, u'Central Plant 1', u'http://egauge.com/'),
(2, u'Central Plant 2', u'http://egauge2.com/'))"
```

**How can I convert this string back to tuples?** I've tried to use `split` a few times but it's very messy and makes a list instead.

Desired output:

```
((1, 'Central Plant 1', 'http://egauge.com/'),
(2, 'Central Plant 2', 'http://egauge2.com/'))
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: How did you get this string in the first place? Are you in control of that part of the process? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use the `literal_eval` method from the `ast` module which you can read more about [**here**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "((1, u'Central Plant 1', u'http://egauge.com/'),(2, u'Central Plant 2', u'http://egauge2.com/'))"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
((1, u'Central Plant 1', u'http://egauge.com/'), (2, u'Central Plant 2', u'http://egauge2.com/'))
```

Answer (score 5):

[`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=literal#ast.literal_eval) should do the trick—***safely***.

E.G.

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("((1, u'Central Plant 1', u'http://egauge.com/'),
... (2, u'Central Plant 2', u'http://egauge2.com/'))")
((1, u'Central Plant 1', u'http://egauge.com/'), (2, u'Central Plant 2', u'http://egauge2.com/'))
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513292/python-make-eval-safe#answer-3513475) for more info on why **not** to use `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Using eval:

```
s="((1, u'Central Plant 1', u'http://egauge.com/'), (2, u'Central Plant 2', u'http://egauge2.com/'))"
p=eval(s)
print p
```