# Safe Python expression evaluation

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I'm writing a totally non-blender related python script, and I noticed Blender has  implemented a solution to a problem I was having.

I'm trying to input a python expression to the program, currently using the `eval()` function. Yet this isn't good security practice. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513292/python-make-eval-safe) for more information. Note that I need operator not to be blocked so `ast.literal_eval()`  can't be used.

Here Blender comes in. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6194/path-for-camera-from-motion-equation/6237#6237) demonstrates a feature in Blender called a scripted python expression box in the driver panel. It achieves exactly what I want my python script to do. I downloaded the blender source to reverse engineer it, but its all C++ not python (even though the expression is evaluated using python syntax).

How is this achieved?

Comment: In short - you need to define your own parser and you should provide your own API for features you want give access too. Look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html and https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html. But you need a lot of experience (and good reviewers) to do it in relatively safe way for anything not banal.

Comment: If the expressions are limited in their complexity, you may be interested in modgrammer: http://pythonhosted.org/modgrammar/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender is effectively using `eval()` and has no attempt at making the expression secure
*(Lookup sandboxing CPython, its not trivial).*

This is why Blend files have an option **Trusted Source**, for more details see:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Security

For the C code, see `BPY_driver_exec`
https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_driver.c$172