# Interpreting a Python string as a conditional statement?

Tags: python

I'm processing some json-formatted log files in python.  It's very straightforward to code some conditional queries, e.g.

```
line=[1,'runtime',{'elapsed':12.3,'jobname':'high38853'}]  # read from json

# split the record and see what jobs take over 30 seconds
key,category,details=line
if category == 'runtime' and details['elapsed'] > 30:
    print details
```

Is there a way to ***safely*** interpret a string as part of a conditional expression, such that I could  accept a conditional on the command line and make it part of my query?

```
search 'details["elapsed"] > 30'
```

so that in code I could do something like this?

```
 if *something involving sys.argv[1]*:
     print line
```

Comment: By "safely" you mean "without `eval`"? If so, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513292/python-make-eval-safe

Comment: Would you be okay with a more 'limited' syntax? E.g. `search 'elapsed > 30'`, or generally, `search 'attribute conditional_operator value'`.

Comment: Also, are the values you need to check against static or dynamic? Meaning, do you know them all in advance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import ast
import operator
import sys

OPERATORS = {
    '<': operator.lt,
    '<=': operator.le,
    '>': operator.gt,
    '>=': operator.ge,
    '==': operator.eq,
    '!=': operator.ne,
    # 'in' is using a lambda because of the opposite operator order
    # 'in': (lambda item, container: operator.contains(container, item),
    'in': (lambda item, container: item in container),
    'contains': operator.contains,
    }


def process_conditionals(conditional_strings, variables):
    for conditional_string in conditional_strings:
        # Everything after first and op is part of second
        first, op, second = conditional_string.split(None, 2)

        resolved_operands = []
        for raw_operand in (first, second):
            try:
                resolved_operand = ast.literal_eval(raw_operand)
            except ValueError:  # If the operand is not a valid literal
                ve = sys.exc_info()
                try:
                    # Check if the operand is a known value
                    resolved_operand = variables[raw_operand]
                except KeyError:  # If the operand is not a known value
                    # Re-raise the ValueError
                    raise ve[1], None, ve[2]

            resolved_operands.append(resolved_operand)

        yield (op, tuple(resolved_operands))


def main(lines, *conditional_strings):
    for line in lines:
        key, category, details = line

        variables = {
            'key': key,
            'category': category,
            'elapsed': details['elapsed'],
            'jobname': details['jobname'],
            }

        conditionals = process_conditionals(conditional_strings, variables)

        try:
            # You could check each conditional separately to determine
            # which ones have errors.
            condition = all(OPERATORS[op](*operands)
                            for op, operands in conditionals)
        except TypeError:
            print("A literal in one of your conditionals is the wrong type. "
                  "If you can't see it, try running each one separately.",
                  file=sys.stderr)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("An operand in one of your conditionals is neither a known "
                  "variable nor a valid literal. If you can't see it, try "
                  "running each one separately.", file=sys.stderr)
            break
        else:
            if condition:
                print(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lines = [
        [1, 'runtime', {'elapsed': 12.3, 'jobname': 'high38853'}],
        [2, 'runtime', {'elapsed': 45.6, 'jobname': 'high38854'}],
        [3, 'runtime', {'elapsed': 78.9, 'jobname': 'high38855'}],
        [4, 'runtime', {'elapsed': 14.7, 'jobname': 'high38856'}],
        [5, 'runtime', {'elapsed': 25.8, 'jobname': 'high38857'}],
        [6, 'runtime', {'elapsed': 36.9, 'jobname': 'high38858'}],
        [7, 'runtime', {'elapsed': 75.3, 'jobname': 'high38859'}],
        ]

    conditional_strings = sys.argv[1:]

    main(lines, *conditional_strings)
```

Examples:

```
$ ./SO_31999444.py 'elapsed > 30'
[2, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38854', 'elapsed': 45.6}]
[3, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38855', 'elapsed': 78.9}]
[6, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38858', 'elapsed': 36.9}]
[7, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38859', 'elapsed': 75.3}]


$ ./SO_31999444.py 'elapsed > 20' 'elapsed < 50'
[2, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38854', 'elapsed': 45.6}]
[5, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38857', 'elapsed': 25.8}]
[6, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38858', 'elapsed': 36.9}]


$ ./SO_31999444.py 'elapsed > 20' 'elapsed < 50' 'key >= 5'
[5, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38857', 'elapsed': 25.8}]
[6, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38858', 'elapsed': 36.9}]


$ ./SO_31999444.py "'9' in jobname"
[7, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38859', 'elapsed': 75.3}]


$ ./SO_31999444.py "jobname contains '9'"
[7, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38859', 'elapsed': 75.3}]


$ ./SO_31999444.py "jobname in ['high38857', 'high38858']"
[5, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38857', 'elapsed': 25.8}]
[6, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38858', 'elapsed': 36.9}]


$ ./SO_31999444.py "9 in jobname"
A literal in one of your conditionals is the wrong type. If you can't see it, try running each one separately.


$ ./SO_31999444.py "notakey == 'something'"
An operand in one of your conditionals is neither a known variable nor a valid literal. If you can't see it, try running each one separately.


$ ./SO_31999444.py "2 == 2"
[1, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38853', 'elapsed': 12.3}]
[2, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38854', 'elapsed': 45.6}]
[3, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38855', 'elapsed': 78.9}]
[4, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38856', 'elapsed': 14.7}]
[5, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38857', 'elapsed': 25.8}]
[6, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38858', 'elapsed': 36.9}]
[7, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38859', 'elapsed': 75.3}]


$ ./SO_31999444.py
[1, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38853', 'elapsed': 12.3}]
[2, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38854', 'elapsed': 45.6}]
[3, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38855', 'elapsed': 78.9}]
[4, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38856', 'elapsed': 14.7}]
[5, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38857', 'elapsed': 25.8}]
[6, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38858', 'elapsed': 36.9}]
[7, 'runtime', {'jobname': 'high38859', 'elapsed': 75.3}]
```

This was a fun little project :).

Comment: @MarkHarrison, thanks :). let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a safe way to do that. For basic conditionals you could parse an input string of a specific format. If your input was in the format "var > 5" you could parse it like this:

```
var, op, num = argv[1].split()
var = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], var) # Get a reference to the data
num = int(num)
if op == ">":
   r = var > num
elif op == "<":
   r = var < num
...

if r:
    <do stuff>
```

To support more complicated statements you would need to improve the parser. If you don't trust your input you should wrap the getattr and int in try/except blocks. To support int or float or another var you would need quite a bit of logic.