# I want to perform arithmetic operation given by condition in string format using values specified in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have got the following condition in **string** format over the network:

```
"value1+value2>value3"
```

I am getting value1, value2 and value3 from certain registers say

```
value1 = readRegister(100), 
value2 = readRegister(200), 
value3 = readRegister(300)
```

So I have created follwing dictonary by reading the register values

```
test_dict = { value1:120, value2: 200, value3: 500}
```

If condition mentioned at starting is true then I have to perform certain operations.

As I mentioned at starting the condition is in **string** format, so I need to fetch and fetch the value of string mentioned in condition from the dictionary that I have created (i.e.  test_dict) and then need to perform the arithematic operation mentioned in condition.

I am not sure how solve this.

Comment: So basically you need to evaluate the expression that comes in string from using the values from yoru dict?

Comment: Where is `readRegister` defined? What is the type of each key in your dict?

Comment: question is very unclear.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32022459/892383); it should get you started.

Comment: I love @NedBatchelders post: [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: @PeterWood, who said anything about `eval()`?

Comment: @Cyphase Not sure I understand. I posted a link about `eval`. Nobody else has mentioned it.

Comment: @PeterWood, sorry, it just seemed a bit out of place because no one had mentioned `eval()` :). Though obviously this is something for which someone _might_ suggest `eval()`.

Comment: @Kevin readRegister() is just function to read value from registers. I have not given its implementation here as I don't find it necessary. I am more concerned about the the values i am getting from these register. The dict I have created is just a value it read from the specific register.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  I want exactly what you have said. I am pretty novice in python.                                                                                          Is there any simple solution to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval`.

First, make sure the input string is absolutely trustworthy. If a malicious user can specify its contents, they can erase your hard drive and send impolite emails to your mother. See the link in Peter Wood's comment for more information.

Then, call `eval`, passing `d` as the globals dict.

```
>>> d = {"value1": 120, "value2": 200, "value3": 500}
>>> s = "value1+value2>value3"
>>> eval(s, d)
False
>>> d = {"value1": 120, "value2": 200, "value3": 300}
>>> eval(s, d)
True
```

This is assuming that your dictionary has string literals as keys. It wasn't clear from your question; I'm assuming you just forgot to write the quote marks.