# Approximating Numerical 2nd Derivative with Python

Tags: python

To preface this question, I understand that it could be done better. But this is a question in a class of mine and I must approach it this way. We cannot use any built in functions or packages.

I need to write a function to approximate the numerical value of the second derivative of a given function using finite difference. The function is below we are using.

[2nd Derivative Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QSsT.jpg) (I lost the login info to my old account so pardon my lack of points and not being able to include images).

My question is this:

I don't understand how to make the python function accept the input function it is to be deriving. If someone puts in the input `2nd_deriv(2x**2 + 4, 6)` I dont understand how to evaluate 2x^2 at 6.

If this is unclear, let me know and I can try again to describe. Python is new to me so I am just getting my feet wet.

Thanks

Comment: Not very familiar with this, but I was looking at `exec` some time ago, which allows you to compile some piece of code from user input. If you want to write a function that can derive any user-input function, this is the way to go, I guess. However, if your problem is just the parsing of the input, this can be done, for example, with `out1 = inputstr.split('(')` followed by `out2 = out1[1].split(', ')`.

Comment: what are the rules for the input?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Without speaking with the professor, it seems like it is any single variable expression.

Comment: I was not clear, I think the input will be formatted for python. I just need to process it in the function

Comment: @ct4242 writing a function that takes the users input and tries to convert it to something `eval` can work with is not difficult for the simple cases. For example `^` can be easily replaced with `**`. And for the multiplications try to look for 2 characters in a row for which the first `pair[0]` returns `True` when `pair[0].isnumeric()` and the second when `pair[1].isalpha()`. When you find them add a `*` between them thus converting `2x` into `2*x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass the function as any other "variable":

```
def f(x):
    return 2*x*x + 4

def d2(fn, x0, h):
    return (fn(x0+h) - 2*fn(x0) + fn(x0-h))/(h*h)

print(d2(f, 6, 0.1))
```

Comment: typo on `f` and `fn`

Comment: i think OP's problem is how to go from `'2x^2+4'` to `2*x**2+4` for the general case.

Comment: in that case, it would probably overlap with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass a literal expression, you need a function (or a lambda).

```
def d2(f, x0, h = 1e-9):
   func = f
   if isinstance(f, str):
      # quite insecure, use only with controlled input
      func = eval ("lambda x:%s" % (f,))
   return (func(x0+h) - 2*func(x0) + func(x0-h))/(2*h)
```

Then to use it

```
def g(x):
   return 2*x**2 + 4

# using explicit function, forcing h value
print d2(g, 6, 1e-10)
```

Or directly:

```
# using lambda and default value for h
print d2(lambda x:2x**2+4, 6)
```

EDIT

- updated to take into account that f can be a string or a function

Comment: i think OP's problem is how to go from `'2x^2+4'` to `2*x**2+4` for the general case.

Comment: modified to handle f provided as a string (quite unsafe though...) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513292/python-make-eval-safe

Comment: Could you explain the lambda? I am not familiar.

Comment: there is a typo on the `return` of the `g(x)` function. Missing a `*`