# Model an equation as a tree

Tags: python, parsing, binary-tree

i want to model an equation as a tree in python. 
for example:

```
x = exp(((-0.5)*((f/sqrt(d))**2)))
```

how do i do this? i want to be able to switch tree branches, 
delete parts of the tree etc, and then convert it back into 
a new equation in text form.

can you give me example code/ Libraries that can do this?

cheers
edit 1:

I have come this far now:

```
import compiler
import pprint
import parser
import ast
class Py2Neko(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def generic_visit(self, node):
        print type(node).__name__
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        print 'Name :', node.id

    def visit_Num(self, node):
        print 'Num :', node.__dict__['n']

    def visit_Str(self, node):
        print "Str :", node.s

    def visit_Print(self, node):
        print "Print :"
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        print "Assign :"
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_Expr(self, node):
        print "Expr :"
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node = ast.parse("res= exp(((-0.5*one)*((delta_w*one/delta*one)**2)))")

    # print ast.dump(node)
    v = Py2Neko()
    v.visit(node)
```

Now it prints all nodes of the tree. However i want to be able to switch branches, 
delete branches, insert branches and change operators/operands.
I need this because i want to be able to mutate the tree randomly.

Comment: [Totally not an answer.](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operators and functions are parent nodes, and operands are the leaves.

```
x = exp(((-0.5)*((f/sqrt(d))**2)))
```

Start with a top-down approach: [ operator { operand1, operand2 }]

```
[ = { x, exp(((-0.5)*((f/sqrt(d))**2))) }]
```

followed by:

```
[ = { x, [ * { exp(((-0.5), ((f/sqrt(d))**2))) }] }]
```

then:

```
[ = { x, [ * { [ exp { -0.5 }],  [ ** { f/sqrt(d)), 2 }] }] }]
```

You get the idea.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python) might be your answer.

Comment: the link was pretty good. it brought me to ast.nodevisitor. If you can tell me how i can swap two branches of the tree or insert/delete branches, then thats an answer.

Comment: Standard operations on any tree data structures.  I'd recommend reading about trees.

Comment: i will just ask another answer, since the question has deviated.

Answer (score 0):

[PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) should be able to help you. (I'm assuming your equation might not necessarily be using the Python syntax itself, strictly speaking.)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to build and work with parse trees. Aside from the built-in parsing, if your equations go outside python's native syntax, take a look at [this overview](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html), which may be dated. Lots of options there.