# Parsing a function from keyboard and executing it

Tags: python

I'm writing an application in Python 3 that processes a lot of mathematical equations. In theory, I'd have to write a different function *inside the code* each time I need this application. I'd like to enter a function (a *mathematical function*) from keyboard, to save *a lot* of time and make this application more versatile.

For example:

```
def readfunction():
    func = input("Type the function you want to solve: ")
    return func
def solve(function)
    # does stuff

solve(readfunction)
```

The question is about "interpreting" input so that, say, if I type x+sin(x) each part is recognised as separate to like x is a variable which I can assign a value to (thus creating a new variable that is NOT in the original code), + is an operator and sin is a function from the module math. That way I can manipulate the function as I please.

How would I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/).

It's an awesome Python-based CAS that does exactly what you wish.

You can import Sage's modules and use its equation parser, as that can handle functions, variables, solve for variables, simplify, etc.

Comment: I knew this program, but I missed the fact that I could import its modules. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `compile`, `eval` and `exec` to create and execute code objects from a string at runtime. See documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile. If you really want to process mathematical formulas, posting [Equation parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/594266/589206) may be of interest as well.