# User input a function

Tags: python, function, input

I'm writing a program that involves calculating the maximum of a user defined function, however if the user enters a function in terms of a variable such as x, i.e.

```
input = x**2 + 2*x + 1
```

I (fairly expectedly) get an error as x is not defined.

Does anyone know of an effective way to allow a user to input a function in terms of a single variable such as x?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python

Comment: int(raw_input("please enter x"))  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not worried about security much, simplest solution is to `eval` the expression e.g.

```
def calculate(value, function):
    x = value
    return eval(function)

print calculate(2, "x**2 + 2*x + 1")
print calculate(2, "x**3 - x**2 + 1")
```

output:

```
9
5
```

You can make it more secure by passing an empty `builtin` dict but still I think some clever code will be able to access internals of your code.

Comment: And then the user can input a value if you used the `int(raw_input(...))` strategy @bpgergo suggested.

Comment: @Jon yes there can be various ways to get `x` value and `function` string from user e.g. from gui or command-line or from an API

Comment: The only thing i can add that maybe would be better to use http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html?highlight=eval#ast.literal_eval

Comment: @ArtsiomRudzenka thanks I may edit that, but I don't think it evaluates such expressions