# String expression parsing in Python using AST

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a string expression like `"((12)*2+(12)+0)"`.

The question is I want to calculate this expression.
I can use `eval()` function. Is there any other way?
I also checked `ast=compiler.parse(eq)` and it return `Module(None, Stmt([Discard(Add((Add((Mul((Const(12), Const(2))), Const(12))), Const(0))))]))` something like that.

How to parse abstract syntax tree?

Comment: You might be able to use [`ast.parse()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) to get the Python AST for a chunk of code.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Coudl you give me little explanation?

Comment: Also, [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) should be able to evaluate maths expressions and then some.

Comment: Not really since I've never used the module, I'm just aware of its existence.

Comment: Please see this post: [Equation parsing in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python).

Comment: That's not an equation, it's an expression.

Comment: There is no simple way. You probably want to check for the [`NodeVisitor`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers) class. Using this you could check if the resulting syntax-tree contains only safe operations, and in this case you could be sure if it is safe to `eval` the expression, or you could eval it by hand while walking the tree.