# Parsing an equation with sub-formulas in python

Tags: python, yacc, lex, equation, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to develop an equation parser using a compiler approach in Python. The main issue that I encounter is that it is more likely that I don't have all the variables and need therefore to look for sub-formulas. Let's show an example that is worth a thousand words ;)

I have four variables whom I know the values: vx, vy, vz and c:

```
list_know_var = ['vx', 'vy', 'vz', 'c']
```

and I want to compute the Mach number (M) defined as

```
equation = 'M = V / c'
```

I already know the c variable but I don't know V. However, I know that the velocity V that can be computed using the vx, vy and vz and this is stored in a dictionary with other formulas (here only one sub formula is shown)

```
know_equations = {'V': '(vx ** 2 + vy ** 2 + vz ** 2) ** 0.5'}
```

Therefore, what I need is to parse the equation and check if I have all the variables. If not, I shall look into the know_equations dictionary to see if an equation is defined for it and this recursively until my equation is well defined.

For now on, I have been able using the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/594360/1379947) to parse my equation and know if I know all the variables. The issue is that I did not find a way to replace the unknown variable (here V) by its expression in know_equation:

```
parsed_equation = compiler.parse(equation)
list_var = re.findall("Name\(\'(\w*)\'\)", str(parsed_equation.getChildNodes()[0]))

list_unknow_var = list(set(list_var) - set(list_know_var))
for var in list_unknow_var:
    if var in know_equations:
        # replace var in equation by its expression given in know_equations
        # and repeate until all the variables are known or raise Error
        pass
```

Thank you in advance for your help, much appreciate!
Adrien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i'm spitballing a bit, but here goes.

The `compiler.parse` function returns an instance of `compiler.ast.Module` which contains an abstract syntax tree. You can traverse this instance using the `getChildNodes` method. By recursively examining the `left` and `right` attributes of the nodes as you traverse the tree you can isolate `compiler.ast.Name` instances and swap them out for your substitution expressions.

So a worked example might be:

```
import compiler

def recursive_parse(node,substitutions):

    # look for left hand side of equation and test
    # if it is a variable name

    if hasattr(node.left,"name"):
        if node.left.name in substitutions.keys():
            node.left = substitutions[node.left.name]
    else:

        # if not, go deeper
        recursive_parse(node.left,substitutions)

    # look for right hand side of equation and test
    # if it is a variable name

    if hasattr(node.right,"name"):
        if node.right.name in substitutions.keys():
            node.right = substitutions[node.right.name]
    else:

        # if not, go deeper
        recursive_parse(node.right,substitutions)

def main(input):        

    substitutions = {
        "r":"sqrt(x**2+y**2)"
    }    

    # each of the substitutions needs to be compiled/parsed
    for key,value in substitutions.items():

        # this is a quick ugly way of getting the data of interest
        # really this should be done in a programatically cleaner manner 
        substitutions[key] = compiler.parse(substitutions[key]).getChildNodes()[0].getChildNodes()[0].getChildNodes()[0]

    # compile the input expression.
    expression = compiler.parse(input)

    print "Input:        ",expression

    # traverse the selected input, here we only pass the branch of interest. 
    # again, as with above, this done quick and dirty.
    recursive_parse(expression.getChildNodes()[0].getChildNodes()[0].getChildNodes()[1],substitutions)

    print "Substituted:  ",expression

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = "t = r*p"
    main(input)
```

I have admittedly only tested this on a handful of use cases, but I think the basis is there  for a generic implementation that can handle a wide variety of inputs.

Running this, I get the output:

```
Input:         Module(None, Stmt([Assign([AssName('t', 'OP_ASSIGN')], Mul((Name('r'), Name('p'))))]))
Substituted:   Module(None, Stmt([Assign([AssName('t', 'OP_ASSIGN')], Mul((CallFunc(Name('sqrt'), [Add((Power((Name('x'), Const(2))), Power((Name('y'), Const(2)))))], None, None), Name('p'))))]))
```

**EDIT:**

So the compiler module is depreciated in Python 3.0, so a better (and cleaner) solution would be to use the `ast` module:

```
import ast
from math import sqrt

# same a previous recursion function but with looking for 'id' not 'name' attribute
def recursive_parse(node,substitutions):
    if hasattr(node.left,"id"):
        if node.left.id in substitutions.keys():
            node.left = substitutions[node.left.id]
    else:
        recursive_parse(node.left,substitutions)

    if hasattr(node.right,"id"):
        if node.right.id in substitutions.keys():
            node.right = substitutions[node.right.id]
    else:
        recursive_parse(node.right,substitutions)

def main(input):

    substitutions = {
        "r":"sqrt(x**2+y**2)"
        }

    for key,value in substitutions.items():
        substitutions[key] = ast.parse(substitutions[key], mode='eval').body

    # As this is an assignment operation, mode must be set to exec
    module = ast.parse(input, mode='exec')

    print "Input:        ",ast.dump(module)

    recursive_parse(module.body[0].value,substitutions)

    print "Substituted:  ",ast.dump(module)

    # give some values for the equation
    x = 3
    y = 2
    p = 1
    code = compile(module,filename='<string>',mode='exec')
    exec(code)

    print input
    print "t =",t


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = "t = r*p"
    main(input)
```

This will compile the expression and execute it in the local space. The output should be:

```
Input:         Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='t', ctx=Store())], value=BinOp(left=Name(id='r', ctx=Load()), op=Mult(), right=Name(id='p', ctx=Load())))])
Substituted:   Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='t', ctx=Store())], value=BinOp(left=Call(func=Name(id='sqrt', ctx=Load()), args=[BinOp(left=BinOp(left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), op=Pow(), right=Num(n=2)), op=Add(), right=BinOp(left=Name(id='y', ctx=Load()), op=Pow(), right=Num(n=2)))], keywords=[], starargs=None, kwargs=None), op=Mult(), right=Name(id='p', ctx=Load())))])
t = r*p
t = 3.60555127546
```

Comment: Thanks !! how can I evaluate the equation afterwards ?

Comment: I have updated to give a better answer that covers how to compile the ast and execute it. Again this isn't totally robust to different inputs, but it should work with all "variable=expression" type inputs. Upvote the answer if it was useful to you.