# Python ast name node replacement deletes the parenthesis

Tags: python, equation, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to develop an equation parser in python with eventually sub formulas. The idea is that a user might give an equation whose variables are not all known. But some sub-formulas might be defined for these undefined variables.

The program should then replace the unknown variable by the sub formula. Using the help provided by @ebarr [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422843/parsing-an-equation-with-sub-formulas-in-python), I have further developed the idea but I fail due to a stupid issue: when replace a variable by a sub-formula, `ast.parse` always deletes the right and left parenthesis which gives a bad final formula.

Any idea on how to preserve the parenthesis?

```
import ast

list_know_var = ['vx', 'vy', 'vz', 'c']
equation = 'M = V  * V / c'
know_equations = {'V': 'vx + 1.'}

# initial equation
parsed_equation = ast.parse(equation)

# the class that automatically dives into the nodes of the AST
# to check for all variables definition
class AdaptEquation(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_name(self, node):
        # checking that the variable is know
        if node.id not in list_know_var:
            if node.id in know_equations.keys():
                node = ast.parse(know_equations[node.id]).body[0].value
        return node

# adapted equation
AdaptEquation().visit(parsed_equation)

# and its human readable expression
import codegen
print('expected equation: M = (vx + 1) * (vx + 1) / c')
>>> expected equation: M = (vx + 1) * (vx + 1) / c
print('adapted equation: ', codegen.to_source(parsed_equation))
>>> adapted equation:  M = vx + 1.0 * vx + 1.0 / c
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Use [Astor](https://github.com/berkerpeksag/astor/) instead of
[Codegen](https://github.com/andreif/codegen).
Even though I appreciate Codegen, I must say its buggy. Astor was built on top of Codegen, is newer and has more features. Here's an example of what you want using Astor:

```python
import astor
import ast
test_code = "x=1-(x+y)"
abstract_syntax_tree = ast.parse(test_code)
print(astor.to_source(abstract_syntax_tree))
print('done')

#output
#x = (1 - (x + y))
#done
```