# Django - Parsing mathematical expression using compiler

Tags: python, django, compiler-construction

I was looking for a field calculator plugin, but I think none exists.

I would like to have ideas or hints about the best way (simplest is the best) I could develop a plugin that allow user to make calculations on fields using mathematical expression.

For beginning I would just let user type an expression in a form and send it through ajax for instance:

```
'field4' = ('field1' + 'field2') / 'field3'
```

Then, I wonder how I could parse such expression (or any other similar) and do the calculation on the server side without bothering with validation for now.

```
import compiler

def fieldCalculator(request):
     queryset = Models.objects.all()

     eq = request.GET['expression']
     ast = compiler.parse(eq)

     #I wonder how to do this part using the parsed expression
     for object in queryset: 
       object.field4 = (object.field1 + object.field2) / object.field3
       object.save()
```

**edit:**

The expression would be user defined, so can take any number of fields and any mathematical operations (lets stay to the + - * / for now).

The expression in its generic way would be:

```
'output_field' = 'a mathematical expression using variables (other fields) and constants'
```

Comment: An interesting idea, but I think you have to do a lot lifting for parsing and validation on user's input, don't you?

Comment: Would the structure of the expression be the same each time? i.e. would it always be field4 = (field1 + field2) / field 3, or could it be field4 = field1 X field2 - field3? The latter problem will be much more difficult.

Comment: yes thats right, validation is a step I can handle, but I bug on parsing the expression correctly

Comment: @alex see edit on that

Comment: I think you should start with looking for exist code for parsing mathematical expression. I bet there are some and it is hard for yourself to build one from scratch.

Comment: @Jerry Meng : yes definately, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Good point @JerryMeng. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python) a good answer from another Stack Overflow question and [here's](http://blog.erezsh.com/how-to-write-a-calculator-in-70-python-lines-by-writing-a-recursive-descent-parser/) a good blog post on writing your own Python calculator.