# Want to enter one variable equation in to program in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is it possible to enter equations in to python program. As an example if I have set equations as below. Is it possible to enter those equations as a user input using input command.

```
  ex:  1/x - 5/a + 2x^2           (a is a constant value)
       1/x + 10x/a^2 - x^2/a^3 + 3x^2
     (all equations have one variable 'x')
```

I now how to define equation using following command. But I want to input that equation as user input.

```
def my_function(x):
        return(1/x + r^2/a -5x^2)

my_function(value for x)
```

Because I want to solve each equation for longer range of x value.
I can write separate program for each equation. But I prefer to give the equation as user input.

Can any one give me a direction to go?

Comment: if you specify that the equation is to be inputted in proper python syntax, and the equations are only algebraic, something like this perhaps: `def my_fun(x, fun): \ return eval(fun)`. Usage: `my_fun(2.0, '1/x - 5*x**2')`. But you should also note the dangers of eval...

Comment: you can use ast.literal_eval to evaluate the input.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

1. grab the user input equation as a string
2. replace the variable a with its value using string.replace
3. parse the string as a mathematical expression. see [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string) for different ways of doing this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `eval()` function.

But;

- The equations have to be in Python syntax.
- The constants and variables have to de defined before evaluating.

Note that using `eval()` exposes a lot of the power of Python. But there are ways to [restrict](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html) it.

An example in iPython:

```
In [1]: x = 2.4

In [2]: a = 5.27

In [3]: eval('1/x - 5/a + 2x^2')
  File "<string>", line 1
    1/x - 5/a + 2x**2
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is because python requires explicit multiplication, and the power operator is `**`, not `^`;

```
In [4]: eval('1/x - 5/a + 2*x**2')
Out[4]: 10.987900063251107

In [5]: eval('1/x + 10*x/a**2 - x**2/a**3 + 3*x**2')
Out[5]: 18.521464252545897

In [6]: eval('1/b')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-555680c1bd65> in <module>()
----> 1 eval('1/b')

<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

You cannot evaluate an expression with a name that hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Eval can be a dangerous function to use, especially since the equations are input by users. The link I posted in my answer below has several alternatives to eval() that can be directly applied to mathematical expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Comment: @JeffTsui If you use a proper `globals` and `locals` argument to `eval()`, you can defang it pretty well. See the "restrict" link in my answer. Having said that, the solution using `ast` is pretty elegant.

Comment: @RolandSmith The "Use eval safely" article you linked to does not protect you: [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)  You cannot easily "defang" eval.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Equation parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python) it might be what you are looking for IF you can write(convert) the equation into python arithmetic.