# Performing operations on variables before assignment of variable values in Python

Tags: python, variables, bezier, polynomials

Ok, so basically my problem is shifting frame of mind from solving math problems „on the paper“ to solving them by programing. Let me explain: I want to know is it possible to perform operations on variable before assigning it a value. Like if I have something like `(1-x)**n` can I firstly assign n a value, then turn it into a from specific for certain degree and then give x a value or values. If I wasn’t clear enough: if n=2  can I firstly turn equation in form `1-2x+x**2` and then in the next step take care of x value?

I want to write a code for calculating and drawing n-th degree Bezier curve .I am using Bernstein polynomials for this, so I realized that equations consists of 3 parts: first part are polynomial coefficients which are all part of Pascal triangle; I am calculating those and putting them in one list. Second part are coordinates of control points which are also some kind of coefficients, and put them in separate list. Now comes the hard part: part of equation that has a variable.Bernsteins are working with barocentric coordinates (meaning u and 1-u).N-th degree formula for this part of equation is:

```
u**i  *(1-u)**(n-i)
```

where n is curve degree, I goes from 0->n  and U is variable.U is acctualy normalised variable,meaning that it value can be from 0 to 1 and i want to itterate it later in certain number of steps (like 1000).But problem is  if i try to use mentioned equation i keep getting error, because Python doesnt know what to do with u.I taught about nested loops in which  first one would itterate a value of  u from 0 to 1 and second would take care of the mentioned equation from 0 to n, but not sure if it is right solution,and no idea how to chech results.What do you think?
PS: I have not uploaded the code because the part with which im having problem i can not even start,and ,I think but could be wrong, that it is separated from the rest of the code; but if you think it can help solving problem i can upload it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python is possibly asking for similar things?

Comment: @hagubear not really sure that it will solve problem,but will test it for sure...thanks

Comment: So what you want to do is keep an expression saved in a variable, Assign values to the variable used in the expression, and then parse the expression so that it uses the values and returns you the result?

Comment: @pythonstarter It seems to me that you want to define a function of one variable, `def f(u): ... ;return computation_value` but I have a hard time to think you're extraneous to this concept...

Comment: @gboffi          I wanted to say "Decorator functions" but the OP clearly is reluctant to use any function - it seems that `mything = "(1-x)**2"` is the first priority. Then, x and n will be declared, either by a script or std io, and then the expression will be evaluated? PyParsing is supposed to be able to do this...

Comment: @gboffi no,im affraid its not that simple,first i need to get to expression of equation whihc depends on the degree and then ill be ok,then it comes to what you said;dooing something with variable u

Comment: @pythonstarter: Would a decorator help here? A function that takes degree of curve as arg and returns a function for Bezier curve of that degree?

Comment: No need to use fancy parsing or decorators, Numpy has functions for basic polynomial math included, see my answer.

Comment: @hagubear actually I want to use n-th degree expression , then parse it and then assign values to variable through a for loop by doing lets say 1000 iteration from 0 to 1

Comment: @aa333 I am not sure if decorative function could operate with U before assigning a value; I think that hagubear and Bas Swinckels have offered different but good solutions...thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Python packages for doing symbolic math, but it might be easier to use some of the [polynomial functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html) available in Numpy. These functions use the convention that a polynomial is represented as an array of coefficients, starting with the lowest order coefficient. So a polynomial `a*x^2 + b*x + c` would be represented as `array([c, b, a])`.

Some examples:

```
In [49]: import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly

In [50]: p = [-1, 1]  # -x + 1

In [51]: p = poly.polypow(p, 2)

In [52]: p # should be 1 - 2x + x^2
Out[52]: array([ 1., -2.,  1.])

In [53]: x = np.arange(10)

In [54]: poly.polyval(x, p)  # evaluate polynomial at points x
Out[54]: array([  1.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   9.,  16.,  25.,  36.,  49.,  64.])
```

And you could calculate your Bernstein polynomial in a way similar to this (there is still a binomial coefficient missing):

```
In [55]: def Bernstein(n, i):
    ...:     part1 = poly.polypow([0, 1], i)  # (0 + u)**i
    ...:     part2 = poly.polypow([1, -1], n - i)  # (1 - u)**(n - i)
    ...:     return poly.polymul(part1, part2)

In [56]: p = Bernstein(3, 2)

In [57]: p
Out[57]: array([ 0.,  0.,  1., -1.])

In [58]: poly.polyval(x, p)  # evaluate polynomial at points x
Out[58]: array([   0.,    0.,   -4.,  -18.,  ..., -448., -648.])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do with **higher-order functions**, that is functions that return functions, like in

```
def Bernstein(n,i):
    def f(t):
        return t**i*(1.0-t)**(n-i)
    return f
```

that you could use like this

```
b52 = Bernstein(5,2)
val = b52(0.74)
```

but instead you'll rather use lists

```
Bernstein_ni = [Bernstein(n,i) for i in range(n+1)]
```

to be used in a higher order function to build the Bezier curve function

```
def mk_bezier(Px,Py):
    "Input, lists of control points, output a function of t that returns (x,y)" 
    n = len(Px)
    binomials = {0:[1], 1:[1,1], 2:[1,2,1],
                 3:[1,3,3,1], 4:[1,4,6,4,1], 5:[1,5,10,10,5,1]}
    binomial = binomials[n-1]
    bPx = [b*x for b,x in zip(binomial,Px)]
    bPy = [b*y for b,y in zip(binomial,Py)]
    bns = [Bernstein(n-1,i) for i in range(n)]
    def f(t):
        x = 0 ; y = 0
        for i in range(n):
            berns = bns[i](t)
            x = x + bPx[i]*berns
            y = y + bPy[i]*berns
        return x, y
    return f
```

eventually, in your program, you can use the function factory like this

```
linear = mk_bezier([0.0,1.0],[1.0,0.0])
quadra = mk_bezier([0.0,1.0,2.0],[1.0,3.0,1.0])

for t in (0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0):
    l = linear(t) ;  q = quadra(t)
    print "%3.1f     (%6.4f,%6.4f)    (%6.4f,%6.4f)" % (t,  l[0],l[1],  q[0],q[1])
```

and this is the testing output

```
0.0     (0.0000,1.0000)    (0.0000,1.0000)
0.1     (0.1000,0.9000)    (0.2000,1.3600)
0.2     (0.2000,0.8000)    (0.4000,1.6400)
0.3     (0.3000,0.7000)    (0.6000,1.8400)
0.4     (0.4000,0.6000)    (0.8000,1.9600)
0.5     (0.5000,0.5000)    (1.0000,2.0000)
0.6     (0.6000,0.4000)    (1.2000,1.9600)
0.7     (0.7000,0.3000)    (1.4000,1.8400)
0.8     (0.8000,0.2000)    (1.6000,1.6400)
0.9     (0.9000,0.1000)    (1.8000,1.3600)
1.0     (1.0000,0.0000)    (2.0000,1.0000)
```

#### Edit

I think that the right way to do it is at the module level, with a top level *sort-of-`defaultdictionary`* that *memoizes* all the different lists required to perform the actual computations, but `defaultdict` doesn't pass a *variable* to its `default_factory` and I don't feel like subclassing `dict` (not now) for the sake of this answer, the main reason being that I've never subclassed before...

#### In response to OP comment

You say that the *function degree* is the main parameter? But it is implicitely defined by length of the list of control points...

```
N   = user_input()
P0x = user_input()
P0y = user_input()
PNx = user_input()
PNy = user_input()
# code that computes P1, ..., PNminus1
orderN = mk_bezier([P0x,P1x,...,PNminus1x,PNx],
                   [P0y,P1y,...,PNminus1y,PNy])

x077, y077 = orderN(0.77)
```

But the customer is always right, so I'll never try again to convince you that my solution works for you if you state that it does things differently from your expectations.

Comment: sorry to all of you,had connection problems so I could not comment, if I got this right,this doesn't really solve my problem,because I tried different approach; my main input for the code is the function degree,and after that im just feeding the code with control points coordinates in a way that seems most natural and user friendly to me; P0x P0y,P1x P1y etc...not sure if I can do that with this code

Comment: @pythonstarter I have just edited my answer, including a response to your comment above. Please note that I'm not trying to persuade you, not at all! I just like to show other users that, at least imho, your objections are unfounded.

Comment: thanks for your answer and help,im sure that your answer is right,that why I gave you my vote (sadly,i can not accept two answers),its not my way of thinking,and i tried different approach,thats all