# Finding repeating operands using regex - Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find through a file expressions such as **A*B**.

A and B could be anything from `[A-Z]` `[a-z]` `[0-9]` and may include `<` `>` `(` `)` `[` `]` `_` `.` etc. but not *commas*, *semicolon*, *whitespace*, *newline* or any other arithmetic operator `(+ - \ *)`. These are the 8 delimiters. Also there can be spaces between A and * and B. Also the number of opening brackets need to be the same as closing brackets in A and B.

I unsuccessfully tried something like this (not taking into account operators inside A and B):

```
import re
fp = open("test", "r")
for line in fp:
    p = re.compile("( |,|;)(.*)[*](.*)( |,|;|\n)")
    m = p.match(line)
        if m:
            print 'Match found ',m.group()
        else:
            print 'No match'
```

**Example 1:**

`(A1 * B1.list(), C * D * E)`
should give 3 matches:

1. A1 * B1.list()
2. C * D
3. D * E

An extension to the problem statement could be that, *commas*, *semicolon*, *whitespace*, *newline* or any other arithmetic operator (+ - \ *) are allowed in A and B if inside backets:

**Example 2:**

`(A * B.max(C * D, E))`
should give 2 matches:

1. A * B.max(C * D, E)
2. C * D

I'm new to regular expressions and curious to find a solution to this.

Comment: Could you furnish some examples, please?

Comment: Use `search` ......... `match` tries to match from the begining.

Comment: You probably want to search for one or more non-separator chatacters, followed by one or more separators, followed by some non-separators again. Check out the `^`.

Comment: According to your current requirements, it is something like [`r'\b[^,;\s+/*-]\s*\*\s*[^,;\s+/*-]\b'`](https://regex101.com/r/jA7kP4/1), but perhaps, you need something really neater. And note you really should use `search`, or `findall`.

Comment: Regular expressions is not a good tool for this particular task. Consider creating a simple parser

Comment: I think this is a dupe of [`Equation parsing in Python`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python). Look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/y5HmFf). How deep can the nested parentheses be?

Comment: [This regex](https://regex101.com/r/jA7kP4/2) is too clumsy, but working for 1 nested level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions have limits. The border between regular expressions and text parsing can be tight. IMO, using a parser is a more robust solution in your case.

The examples in the question suggest recursive patterns. A parser is again superior than a regex flavor in this area.

Have a look to this proposed solution: [Equation parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python).