# How to solve a math equation if the input is a string in python?

Tags: string, python-2.7, math

If the input is a string (ex. 2 + 2 = ), how can I make it to do the operation? I tried using eval, but that doesn't take the =, and also it doesn't print decimals. Also I tried split().

Thank you in advance,

Comment: remove the `=`. If you want to do it in a safe way you have to tell us what kind of operations and notations do you want to support. Do your operators have precedence, etc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python

Comment: it would be regular +, -, * and /. Thank you

Comment: Show us code you tried and what the desired input and output are and what you got instead. No, we won't write your parser for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split at the '+' sign `numbers=input.split('+')`, then remove the '=' form the end, `secondNumber=numbers.split('=')`. Afther that write

```
 if operator == '+':
   output = numbers[0] + secondNumber[0]
   print(output)
```

Or just `output=eval(input.split('=')[0])`