# Regex repeating sequence matching

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I don't have a lot of experience with regular expressions, and I'm breaking my head over this one.

I have the following string: `(2*8)+(3*3)`

I want to retrieve `2*8` and `3*3`, but the character between the parentheses can vary,

If i use the following regex: `r'\((.*)\)'`

I get `2*8)+(3*3`

How do I get `2*8` and `3*3`?

Comment: @SebastianProske This problem smells like maybe it needs a parser, certainly if there could be nested parentheses.

Comment: ah i got a bit further, thank you, but now when i try to match

(2*(3*7))+(2+2),

it leaves a parentheses behind

Comment: Use a parser, it will be much more readable

Comment: could you direct me to a parser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python