# Unpack regex list comprehension

Tags: python

Did some research, and asked someone on Stack if they could help me with a polynomial converter to take a polynomial and turn it into a list - Ex: `3x^2 - 8x + 5` --- `[3, -8, 5]`. They did an excellent job with it, however it is a bit over my head in terms of whats going on. Was wondering if anyone would be willing to give me a detailed breakdown on what's happening and help me rewrite it to make sure I understand what's going on when I come back to it. (Using regex btw) Here it is:

```
poly = ("4x^2 - 3x + 2")
s=re.sub('[xX^]','',poly)
print([int('-'+i[0]) if s[s.index(i)-2]=='-' else int(i[0]) for i in re.split(' [+|-] ',s)])
```

I tried putting it in terms that make sense to me order-wise but I don't really know what to do because it doesn't work.

```
if s[s.index(i) - 2]=="-":
    int("-" + i[0])
else:
    int(i[0])
    for i in re.split:
        (" [+|-] ", s)
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: That's certainly not what I would consider an "excellent job". It doesn't handle multi-digit coefficients, a minus sign on the leading term, or implicit "1" coefficients, and a lot of the regex parts are either superfluous or wrong - for example, `|` is not alternation inside a character class.

Comment: @user2357112 Maybe leave feedback on the actual answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716077/storing-specific-whole-numbers-python

Comment: Are you aware of [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)?

Comment: @tripleee: Yeah, I've posted there too now.

Comment: Also, even worse problem: `index` frequently returns a different index from the index you're looking for, leading to results like [`'3x^2 - 3x - 3'` getting parsed as `[3, 3, 3]`](https://ideone.com/QMdEP9).

Comment: @o11c There's another answer on the original question which suggests sympy

Comment: @user2357112 indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in re.split(' [+|-] ',s):
    if s[s.index(i) - 2]=="-":
        x.append(int("-" + i[0]))
    else:
        x.append(int(i[0]))
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[4, -3, 2]
```

First, You need to understand how list comprehension works, in your code

```
[ `firstValue`  if `condition` else  `secondValue` while iterating over list]
```

So, 
the this small code, is iterating over a for loop (the for loop should be outside) evaluating condition on each element, and appending the output to main list.

Comment: That makes SO much more sense! I've never even heard of list comprehension so thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem!

Another classic case of Python over-compression! List comprehensions can be a nightmare, and I hate to see them thrown at beginners. I also noticed a few potential problems with that approach, so I'd like to offer an alternative. For a value add, this will also keep track of the power of each term. I've commented the approach.

```
#   This is hopefully self-explanatory.
poly = "4x^2 - 3x^3 - 2x + 2"
#   We made this regex more complicated in order to capture an entire
#   term of a polynomial. Here's how that works:
#   ([+-]|)     - The first capture group, contain the sign or (|)
#                 nothing.
#   \s*         - Allow whitespace between the sign and the term.
#   ([0-9]+)    - The second capture group, contain the coefficient.
#   ([xX]|)     - Match the variable or nothing.
#   (\^[0-9]+|) - Match the exponent or nothing. Notice we escape the caret.
matches = re.finditer(r'([+-]|)\s*([0-9]+)([xX]|)(\^[0-9]+|)', poly)

#   Now we parse the results of the regex...
terms = list() # Create a list to store our processed terms.
for match in matches: # Iterate our matches.
    #   Step 1: Parse the groups' contents.
    negative = match.group(1) == '-' # Check if the sign is negative.
    coef = int(match.group(2)) # Retrieve the coefficient as an integer.
    has_variable = bool(match.group(3)) # Check whether there's a variable.
    exponent_str = match.group(4) # Get the exponent group.
    if exponent_str:
        #   There's an exponent, remove the caret and turn it into an
        #   integer.
        exponent = int(exponent_str[1:])
    else:
        #   There's no exponent, if there's a variable the power of this term
        #   is 1, otherwise it's 0.
        exponent = 1 if has_variable else 0

    #   Step 2: Create a (coefficient, power) tuple and add it to the list of
    #   terms.
    if negative:
        #   Make the coefficient negative if the sign was a -.
        coef *= -1
    #   Add a tuple containing the coefficient and exponent to our list of
    #   terms.
    terms.append((coef, exponent))

#   Optional: sort the terms in order of power (descending).
terms.sort(key=lambda tpl: -tpl[1])

#   Print the output.
print(terms)
```

This will output

```
[(-3, 3), (4, 2), (-2, 1), (2, 0)]
```