# Equation Solving with python

Tags: python, equation-solving

There is a question like that:

1 `X`2 `X` 3 `X` 4 `X` 5 `X` 6 `X` 7 `X` 8 `X` 9 = 1942

`X` = must be x,+,-,÷ operators or nothing(89, 123 could be etc.)

How can i solve this problem with python?

Thanks.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594266/equation-parsing-in-python

Comment: How would you go about solving this in the first place? When you have an idea, translate that into Python. When you get stuck, you can ask here for help. Be sure to include code when asking your question.

Comment: Is this a challenge from Project Euler?

Comment: i am not sure @Yes . My friend asked me. He faced in a intelligence test challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
from itertools import product
target = 1942
test_str = "1{0[0]}2{0[1]}3{0[2]}4{0[3]}5{0[4]}6{0[5]}7{0[6]}8{0[7]}9"
for a in product(["*", "", "+", "/", "-", ""], repeat=8): # Iterate all posibilites
  result_str = test_str.format(a)
  if eval(result_str) == target:
    print(result_str)
    break
```

And optimize and make it more expandable to more numbers. But for your specific problem this works fine. I found this solution:

> `1*2/3+4*56*78/9`

Take a look at [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parser` module from python

```
import parser
formula = "1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9"
code = parser.expr(formula).compile()
print eval(code)
```